# Django objects.get() function does not work but objects.filter().first() works

Tags: python, django, backend, web-development-server

When I look up for the user with

`User.objects.get(username=username)`

it shows error

> User matching query does not exist

but it works fine with `User.objects.filter(username=username).first()`

why does this happen?

Comment: Because `.first()` **returns `None`** in case there is no record.

Answer (score 3):

The two are not equivalent. [**`.get(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get) will raise an exception in two cases:

1. when there is no `User` with the given `username`; and
2. when there are *multiple* `User`s with the given `username`, although here that is impossible, since the `username` is a `unique=True` field.

[**`.first(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#first) on the other hand will not raise an exception. In case *no* record is returned, it will return `None`. In case there are *multiple* records that match, it will simply return the first one.

It is however often not a good idea to pass errors silently. In case you expect a user, using `.first()` will result in `None`, but this can mean that the logic later in the view that expects a `User` object will either raise errors, or make mistakes. In a view often [**`get_object_or_404`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) is used to raise a `Http404` in case no object exists, this thus means that the view will respond with a HTTP 404 response.