# DoesNotExist at /.../pk/

Tags: python, django, django-models

So I created a simple CRUD simple, like a tweet, where you have Username, Title and Message/Description

It was working well and I was following a tutorial, then it happened

[image]

I don't know what going on because my models seems to be ok

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    

class Room(models.Model):
    host = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    #participants =
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering =  ['-updated', '-created']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
class Message(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField()
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
       return self.body[0:50]
```

It also doesn't seem to be an error in my views

```
def room(requests,pk):
   room = Room.objects.get(id=pk)
   message = Message.objects.get(id=pk)
   context = {'room':room, 'message':message}
   return render(requests,'base/buy.html',context)

def createRoom(request):
   form = RoomForm()
   if request.method == 'POST':
       form = RoomForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
           form.save()
           return redirect('home')

   context = {'form':form}
   return render(request, 'base/room_form.html', context)
```

But then I noticed this error in my shell

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\adrya\thegreatsite\base\views.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .models import Room, Message
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

these are the models I imported

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Room, Message
from .forms import RoomForm
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django objects.get() function does not work but objects.filter().first() works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64403629/django-objects-get-function-does-not-work-but-objects-filter-first-works)